# Should the sensor assembly on an Olympus E-PL7 move freely when power is off?

Tags: sensor, image-stabilization, olympus, micro-four-thirds

I just purchased (new) an E-PL7 as a backup for my aging E-PL6 body. It appears to function perfectly, but when powered off a slight clunking sound can be heard if the camera is lightly shaken along its top-to-bottom axis (and slightly less so side-to-side). With no lens mounted, I can see the sensor assembly shifting a millimeter or two as the source of the sound. When the power is on, all passive movement vanishes and the image stabilization system works as it should.

Is this normal, or should something be holding the sensor assembly more firmly in place when the camera is powered down? (The E-PL6 doesn't exhibit similar behavior, but it uses a different, less sophisticated 2-axis stabilization system.)

Olympus tech support says it's normal (unsurprisingly), while several Micro 4/3 forum members who own the camera initially said it was not (although others later confirmed that it was - apparently some people just don't notice stuff like that...).

Comment: This is probably a question you should ask Olympus.

Comment: Olympus tech support says it's normal (unsurprisingly), while several m43 forum members who own the camera say it is not. My confidence level is probably higher for SE than for either of those sources, but if the question is not objectively answerable enough to be here, then I won't complain if it's closed.

Comment: My concern is that there may not be that many, if any, active members here that have an E-PL7. And even if they do, how would they know whether their sensor is or is not about to fall out of the camera from all of the movement?

Comment: See also: [sensor hangs loose in the body when camera is switched off](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/sensor-hangs-loose-in-the-body-when-camera-is-switched-off)

Answer (score 3):

According to Olympus support (and eventually other users of the camera) this is normal expected behavior, and indeed was also the case with a second copy I later acquired.