# Sensor hangs loose in the body when camera is switched off

Tags: sensor, image-stabilization, micro-four-thirds

I own a Panasonic DMC-G81 (same as G80/G85) with in-body Image Stabilization.

When turned on everything is just fine, but when turned off, the sensor is wobbling around in the body. When no lens attached, it's clearly visible moving about 1/2 cm in the body. I didn't find anything about it in the internet. Shouldn't the sensor be in a kind of parking position, should I worry about the sensor ?

I'm not sure if that is the usual behavior, maybe someone with the same or similar body can have a look.

Comment: See also: [Should the sensor assembly on an olympus E-PL7 move freely when power is off?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85404/should-the-sensor-assembly-on-an-olympus-e-pl7-move-freely-when-power-is-off)

Comment: This behavior is normal. When the image stabilization system is disengaged, the image sensor (and the plate it is mounted on) isn't held down and can move freely.

Answer (score 2):

I have a "sensor IBIS assembly" that was swapped due to failure and I have seen the old assembly. As far as I can tell about technologies used for stabilization, it uses an electromagnetic positioning technology, similar to that used for read/write head positioning in computer hard drives.

The sensor has electromagnetic coils and it glides between magnets. There is a movement limiter (size about 5*5mm), but no parking feature. When you turn on the camera, the sensor is positioned in the center by electromagnetic force. This technology is very precise because this technology has been used in HDDs for many years to precisely position heads in very small increments.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the In Body Image stabilisation (IBIS) is turn off, it quite normal.

Some solutions put the sensor in a parking position (like Sony does), but both solutions are fine.

Comment: Thanks! Could you add some information on how you got that knowledge?

Comment: I have uses an GX85 and it did indeed clunks around when the camera was off.  My own Sony cameras never do this and they all have IBIS, so I don't have links, only IRL experiences.

Comment: When turning off the IBIS while shooting, the sensor should still be in a stable position.

Comment: I would not say that both solutions are "fine".  A sensor that is moving around freely is constantly flexing the wires that connect the sensor to the rest of the hardware.  That's a pretty seriously bad design, IMO.